# Is it needed Adobe DNG Converter when Photoshop & Lightroom are already installed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I already have Photoshop & Lightroom installed.
Do I need Adobe DNG Converter [[1](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html),[2](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Windows)]?
Will this program add the possibility to raw import from more devices?

Comment: Welcome on Super __user__. If you want any answer or attention please respect the time that people can present you writing more correctly your question. You may want to read [how-to-ask](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it seems you do not. Indeed you can read on the Camera Raw page <sup>[[1](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/supported-cameras.html)]</sup>.

> Adobe Camera Raw, which lets you import and enhance raw images, has been a must-have tool for professional photographers right since it was first released in 2003. Applications that support Adobe Camera Raw include Photoshop, Photoshop Elements, After Effects, and Bridge. **Additionally, Adobe Lightroom is built upon the same powerful raw image processing technology that powers Adobe Camera Raw**.

From the Adobe DNG Converter page <sup>[[2](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5919)]</sup> you can read:

> The Adobe DNG Converter is a free utility that enables you to easily convert camera-specific raw files from more than 350 cameras to the more universal DNG raw format
>   ...
>   Support for the following cameras has been added. **Visit the Camera Raw page for a complete list of supported cameras <sup>[[1](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/supported-cameras.html)]</sup>.**

...that is the page reported above. So it seems to be a duplicate.

In general, on any system, it's better to avoid to install unneeded software.
Since  Adobe DNG Converter (at present version 9.1.1) is a free utility if you have space you can download and in case of need install.

**Update**
From this page <sup>[[3](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=106&platform=Windows)]</sup>, it's possible to download the version 9.3... but it doesn't seems to change what above.